# Node-red HTTP GET Request in Angular 4 webapp

Tags: angular, typescript, node-red, angular4-httpclient

I'm building a service that use **Node-red** only to send email when a GET request to **127.0.0.1:1880/hello** (node-red port) are triggered and an **Angular 4 webapp** (**127.0.0.1:3000**) to client access.

When i access thr /hello page from **browser**, i get an e-mail from node-red in my personal e-mail  account.

The problem is that when press the button for test an http get request to node-red, **nothing happens.**

**Using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**

**node 8.15**

**npm 6.4**

**Node-RED 0.20.2**

**The node-red flow:**

[NODE-RED FLOW SEND EMAIL IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaFqu.png)

> [{"id":"35dcdbd9.a99684","type":"tab","label":"Flow
>   1","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"dcdb9a4e.db2eb8","type":"debug","z":"35dcdbd9.a99684","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"payload","targetType":"msg","x":450,"y":180,"wires":[]},{"id":"aa98d38f.846af","type":"e-mail","z":"35dcdbd9.a99684","server":"smtp.gmail.com","port":"465","secure":true,"tls":true,"name":"andre.def93@gmail.com","dname":"","x":500,"y":320,"wires":[]},{"id":"f1aea493.ec0e78","type":"http
>   response","z":"35dcdbd9.a99684","name":"","statusCode":"","headers":{},"x":670,"y":260,"wires":[]},{"id":"747c3f58.892dd","type":"http
>   in","z":"35dcdbd9.a99684","name":"","url":"/hello","method":"get","upload":false,"swaggerDoc":"","x":120,"y":260,"wires":[["dcdb9a4e.db2eb8","aa98d38f.846af","f1aea493.ec0e78"]]}]

**Angular 4.1.3 app**

My component.ts:

```
[...]
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
[...]
    constructor(
        private http: Http,
        [...]
    ) { }
[...]
    test(){
       this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:1880/hello');
    }
[...]
```

My component.html:

```
[...]
<button class="primary" (click)="test()">
    <div *ngIf="!issueInProgress">
        <span>TEST</span>
    </div>
</button>
[...]
```

Thank you all folks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possible problems.
First, i recommend you use http client.

(in App Module):

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
imports: [ .. ,HttpClientModule, .. ]
```

(in Component.ts (Is better in a service)

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

.... 

 constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

test(){
 this.http.get<any>('http://127.0.0.1:1800/hello').subscribe(data=>{
 console.log("Work, recive: " + data);
},
err =>{
 console.log("Err, recive: " + err);
},
() => {
 console.log("Finish");
});
}
```

in this way, you will be able to see what the error is and why it is not working.

if is a CORS error, try: 
https://github.com/node-red/node-red/issues/1347#issuecomment-363451534

 or 
https://thefrinkiac7.wordpress.com/node-red/enable-cors-with-node-red/

:) Bye!

Comment: Thanks mate, but i think that because of my Angular version 4.1.3, im not able to use import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; i try to update putting "^" in front of angular depedencies in package.json but this broken many parts of webapp.
You think that have other way to use http get request in Angular 4.1.3 without update? 

Thank again

Comment: works but with 
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http'; (MODULE)
and
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
 this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:1880/hello',{
            "to": "andre.def93@gmail.com", "topic":"New revision recieved"
        }).subscribe(data=>{
        console.log("Work, recive: " + data);
       },
       err =>{
        console.log("Err, recive: " + err);
       },
       () => {
        console.log("Finish");
       });
Thanks mate!

Comment: Excelent! sorry for the delay